# add Text right bottom of the its parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to add a clock to my component right-bottom here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text } from "react-native";
import CircleCard from "./CircleCard"; 
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function ChatCard() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <CircleCard />{// my component}
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          flex: 1,
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          flexShrink: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "gray" }} numberOfLines={1}>{//For parsing }
          SomeRandomLettersSomeRandomLettersSomeRandomLettersSomeRandomLetters  {//The message part}
        </Text>

        <Text style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, right: 0 }}>18:48</Text> {//The clock bottom right}
      </View>
      <View style={{ margin: 15 }}> {//For Icon}
        <MaterialIcons
          name="keyboard-arrow-right"
          size={40}
          color="black"
          style={{ width: 30 }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 80,
    margin: 5,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
});
```

i added it at the end but now the First  and Second Text overlaped.

Also an image for my goal:

[image]

Note2 : I read that the position absolute violate the flex-box but i do not find any style for moving the Text component to end. If there is an other way. i will be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is what you want actually but here is my solution:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function ChatCard() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.image}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 34 }}>B</Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={styles.rowContent}
      >
        <Text style={styles.longText} ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={1}>
          SomeRandomLettersSomeRandomLettersSomeRandomLettersSomeRandomLetters  
        </Text>

        <Text style={styles.time}>18:48</Text> 
      </View>
      <View style={{ margin: 15 }}>
        <MaterialIcons
          name="keyboard-arrow-right"
          size={40}
          color="black"
          style={{ width: 30 }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 30,
    width: '100%',
    height: 80,
    margin: 5,
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  image: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 70,
    padding: 10,
  },
  rowContent: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1
  },
  longText: { 
    color: "gray", 
    alignSelf: 'stretch', 
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  time: { alignSelf: 'flex-end' }
});
```